# Get an element with its index counting from the end in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, list, kotlin, slice

Is there a simple function to get an element with its index counting from the end in a Kotlin `Array`, `List`, or `String`? In other words, is there a Kotlin equivalent of negative index slicing in Python?

Comment: For read access: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take-last.html. So far `last` covers 99% of my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct function for slicing, but one can write an user defined function or easily simulate  using `reversed` function, that works with string, lists and arrays.

Strings In *Python*

```
pyString = 'Python'
sObject = slice(-1, -4, -1)
print(pyString[sObject])    # output: noh
```

Strings In *Kotlin*

```
val pyString = "Python"
val sObject = pyString.reversed().substring(0, 3).reversed()  // index 3 excluded
println(pyString)    // output: noh
```

List(or Arrays) in *Kotlin*

```
var py = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
var sObject = py.reversed().slice(0..2).reversed()
println(sObject)
```

However you can do method or function overload, using `this` as implicit object

For instance, you can program `reverse substring`, but here you cannot use negative numbers, because we  need a different parameters profile regarding to the original method:

```
fun String.substring(a: Int, b: Int = 0, rev: Boolean): String {
    if (rev == true)
        if (b == 0)
            return this.substring(0, this.length - a)
        else
            return this.substring(this.length - b, this.length - a)
    else
        if (b == 0)
            return this.substring(a)
        else
            return this.substring(a, b)
}
```

So `"whale".substring(0,2,true)` is `"le"`

You can use similar technique to extend `slice` method.

Comment: Your code doesn't match [Coding Conventions - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#horizontal-whitespace). Please add necessary whitespaces or format using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Now I've copied and pasted directly from `Android Studio`, after `Ctrl+Alt+L` (Auto formatting command). No compiling or warning error.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a function similar to python's slicing mechanism

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.abs


fun String.substring(startingIndex: Int, endingIndex: Int, step: Int=1): String {
    var start = startingIndex
    var end = endingIndex
    var string = this

    if (start < 0) {
        start = string.length + start
    }
    if (end < 0) {
        end = string.length + end
    }
    
    if (step < 0) {
        string = string.reversed()
    }
    
    if (start >= string.length) {
        throw Exception("Index out of bounds.")
    }
    
    var outString = ""
    
    for ((index, character) in string.withIndex()) {
        if (index % abs(step) == 0) {
            if (index >= start && index <= end) {
                outString += character
            }
        }
    }
    return outString
}
```

Can be used like this:

```kotlin
println("This is some text.".substring(8, -6))  // some
```

There is but on problem with my function, it is that a negative step messes it up if you also use negative indexes.

Answer (score 0):

These answers are quite complicated. If you just want to use a negative index, all you have to do is
`exampleList[exampleList.lastIndex - exampleIndex]` which will (basically) do the same as `exampleList[-exampleindex]` in python.
So for example you would do:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val exampleList = mutableListOf<Int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    //Now we want exampleList[-1] or 4. I know in python it would be writen as exampleList[-2], but don't worry about that!
    println(exampleList[exampleList.lastIndex - 1])
}
```

the `lastIndex` parameter is the key thing to remember.